# telegraf input exec

Tags: telegraf

Есть bash скрипт, который я пытаюсь вызвать в input telegraf exec (https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/release-1.19/plugins/inputs/exec/README.md)

```
URL=my_domain; \
HTTP_CODE=$(curl -Lo /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}" $URL); \
echo cert_validator,url=$URL code=$HTTP_CODE
```

Bash скрипт сам по себе выполняется, но в связке с telegraf работает, если вынести bash скрипт в отдельный файл.
Есть ли возможность выполнить этот скрипт не вынося bash скрипт в отдельный файл ?